# How to add a checkbox to Kendo UI MVC grid and pass a parameter when button clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Sorry if this question has a very simple answer, I'm new in all this thing...

This is my Kendo UI grid with a copyToClipboard button:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Where(o => o.TypeID == 1)).Name("Grid").TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid" })
              .ToolBar(o => o.Template(@<text>
                        <ul class='ul-bulk-menu'>
                            <li><button type="button" id='copyToClip' class='t-button t-button-icon' title='Copy To ClipBoard'></button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </text>))

              .Columns(col =>
              {
                  col.Bound(c => c.AttackID).Hidden().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "attackId" });
                  col.Bound(c => c.WhiteboardId).Hidden().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "whiteboardid-cell" });
                  col.Bound(c => c.EntityName).Title("Entity");
                  col.Bound(c => c.ElementId).Title("Element");
                  col.Bound(c => c.Url).ClientTemplate(hyperUrl).Title("Domain").Template(o => string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", o.Url, o.Domain));
                  col.Bound(c => c.Functionality).Title("Functionality");
                  col.Bound(c => c.shortDurationStatus).Title("Status");
                  col.Bound(c => c.SLHandledBy).Title("Handled By");
                  col.Bound(c => c.DurationInt).Title("Duration");

                  col.Bound(c => c.AttackID).Title("Command").Template(@<text>
                    <button id="@item.AttackID" onclick="assignAnalyst(@item.AttackID, @item.TypeID, this)">Edit</button>
                </text>);

              })
                .Sortable()
                .Groupable()
                .Filterable()
                .Scrollable(o => o.Height(height))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server().Model(model => model.Id(o => o.AttackID)))
        )
```

I'm trying to add a checkbox column to my grid.
When some rows are checked and the 'copyToClip' button is clicked, I need to pass the 'AttackID' parameter of all checked rows to a function which will copy to clipboard some data from database.

Is it possible?

(Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example I found from this [source](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-display-checkboxes-in-ajax-bound-grids). I've never tried this before, but hopefully this will get you in the right direction.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Enabled).ClientTemplate(
    "<input type='checkbox' value='#= ProductID #' " +
        "# if (Enabled) { #" +
            "checked='checked'" +
        "# } #" +
    "/>"
);
```